# Request stuck in pending

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, create-react-app

When I try to make a POST request using react with express the request stucks in the middleware of the request. For the front end part I'm using CRA of React and express js for the backend.
I'm not sure where is the problem but any advices will be very helpfull.

Backend

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true,
  optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use("/contact", contact);
app.use("/offer", offer);

app.listen(3015);
```

index.js

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var cors = require('cors');
const creds = require('../../config');
const app = express();
const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true,
  optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};

// Multiple routing
const router1 = express.Router();
const router2 = express.Router();

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/contact', router1);
app.use('/offer', router2);
app.set('port', 3015);

var transport = {
  host: 'kelvin.superhosting.bg',
  port: 587,
  auth: {
    user: creds.USER,
    pass: creds.PASS
  }
}
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transport)
transporter.verify((error, success) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(success);
    // console.log('Server is ready to take messages');
  }
});

exports.contact = () => {
  router1.post('/contact', (req, res, next) => {
    // console.log('req.body', req.body);
    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var subject = req.body.subject;
    var message = req.body.message;
    var content = `name: ${name} \n email: ${email} \n\n message: ${message} `;
    var mail = {
      from: name,
      to: 'sales@pokrivala.net',  // Change to email address that you want to receive messages on
      subject: subject,
      text: content
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('err', err)
        res.json({
          status: 'fail'
        })
      } else {
        console.log('here');
        res.json({
          status: 'success'
        })
      }
    });
    next();
  });
}

exports.offer = async () => {
  await router2.post('/offer', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('req.body', req.body);
    var subject = "Hey this is a subject example";
    var mail = {
      to: 'sales@pokrivala.net',  // Change to email address that you want to receive messages on
      subject: subject,
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: `${req.body.attachments[0].filename}`,
          content: `${req.body.attachments[0].content}`,
          encoding: `${req.body.attachments[0].encoding}`,
        },
      ],
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          status: 'fail'
        })
      } else {
        res.json({
          status: 'success'
        })
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Fronend
index.jsx

```
async function fetchMessage() {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3015/contact`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(values[0]),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    }).then(
      (response) => (response.json())
    ).then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 'success') {
        setValues([]);
        setName('');
        setEmail('');
        setSubject('');
        setMessage('');
        setCaptchaText('');
        onRefresh();
        setMessageOpen(true);
      } else if (response.status === 'fail') {
        console.log("Message failed to send.", response)
      }
    });

    return response;
  }
```

Also I try a couple of ways to resolve this issue. For example with/without async/await both in the fronend and backend, multiple times I restart the server and also my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller functions (`contact` and `offer`) you're using `nodemailer`'s `sendMail` with a callback function. That's why your request is stuck at the backend, you are registering a callback and immediately your code moves to `next`, so you're not sending a response to the client.

You can use `sendMail` without a callback function, it will return a Promise, await this promise and use it in `try/catch` block, send success response if the Promise is resolved or send an error if it's rejected, similar to this,

```
try {
const info = await transporter.sendMail(mail);
console.log('here');
res.json({
    status: 'success'
})} catch (err) {
console.log('err', err)
res.json({
    status: 'fail'
})
```

}

Comment: also, your frontend code with a request to the backend is not correct, you can't use await, and then together, try to use only await inside the try/catch block for better readability.

Comment: @Santiya please pay attention to your controller function, you can use the callback function inside router1 and router2 as a controller function, you don't need to wrap them in another function.

Comment: @Paviz, could you attach example with code which you explain above, please ?